# Parse non-standard XML using XElement

Tags: xml, vb.net

Im having a hard time parsing this XML. I need to extract the IP address for any given extension. The XML is sent back as such:

```
<response method="switchvox.status.phones.getList">
   <result>
      <sip_phones page_number="1" total_pages="1" items_per_page="50" total_items="29">
          <sip_phone id="1113" extension="220" caller_id="A" user_agent="PolycomSoundPointIP-SPIP_330-UA/3.2.6.0314" ip_address="192.168.6.86" state="registered" />
          <sip_phone id="1359" extension="204" caller_id="B" user_agent="PolycomSoundPointIP-SPIP_330-UA/3.2.6.0314" ip_address="192.168.6.41" state="registered" />
          <sip_phone id="1354" extension="203" caller_id="C" user_agent="PolycomSoundPointIP-SPIP_330-UA/3.3.4.0085" ip_address="173.10.52.177" state="registered" />
     </sip_phones>
   </result>
</response>
```

It is returned back from the API and parsed in as XElement.

```
 Public Function GetInfo() As XElement
    Dim xml As XElement = <request method="switchvox.status.phones.getList">
                          </request>

    Const url As String = "https://pbx/xml"
    Dim webRequest__1 As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    webRequest__1.Method = "POST"
    webRequest__1.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "pass")
    webRequest__1.ContentType = "text/xml"
    webRequest__1.ContentLength = xml.ToString().Length
    Using requestWriter2 As New StreamWriter(webRequest__1.GetRequestStream())
        requestWriter2.Write(xml.ToString())
    End Using
    Using resp As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(webRequest__1.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Using responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream()
            Return (XElement.Load(responseStream))
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: What is the issue?  Are you seeing an error in the code you provided?  If so, what is the error?  Is it just that you need to retrieve IP address from the XML?  If so, I suggest reading up on how to use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to query for the value.

Comment: I cant get XPath to return the correct value

Comment: What is the XPath that you are using?  Could you post your code you have for retrieving the IP address from the `XElement`?